# Firebug and self-invoking anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, firebug, anonymous-function

My basic setup is a whole heap of Javascript under an anonymous self-invoking function:

```
(function () {
    ...
})();
```

My problem is that I can't seem to get access to the objects within this ASI function via the DOM tab. I tried both the following:

```
var MYAPP = function () {
    ...
};

var MYAPP = (function () {
    ...
})();
```

The first didn't fire at all. The second just said MYAPP is `undefined` in the DOM tab.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Have you return anything in the second form?

Comment: @wong2  No, I don't return anything. It's just an attempt to create a namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first version, you are simply creating a function with the name `MYAPP`, but you are not executing it.

In the second version, your function is executed and its result is assigned to `MYAPP`. But your function does not seem to return anything, so `MYAPP` stays undefined.

See [A Javascript Module Pattern](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/) on YUIBlog for an explanation of this pattern. Their example goes like this:

```
YAHOO.myProject.myModule = function () {

    return  {
        myPublicProperty: "I'm accessible as YAHOO.myProject.myModule.myPublicProperty.",
        myPublicMethod: function () {
            YAHOO.log("I'm accessible as YAHOO.myProject.myModule.myPublicMethod.");
        }
    };

}(); // the parens here cause the anonymous function to execute and return
```

So your function basically returns an object containing all the public members. You can then access these with Firebug, too.

Comment: Thanks for this. Crockford has a similar pattern, I've now remembered, although I'd not thought of using it to this extent.